# Is java a good start to learn OOP?

Tags: java, object-oriented

I have good teacher who understands OOP. However, the language which he is expert in is Java and I don't want to learn Java.

My question is, do you think if I learn OOP using Java I will waste my time? And do you think it is good to start to learn OOP?

Comment: **" if I learn OOP using Java will I waste my time"**  No way...

Comment: I took an OOP class in college, because I wanted to learn C++.  They taught me Java. :)

Comment: **"But I don't want to learn Java"** - Python could be a good alternative.

Comment: A good teacher can teach you object orientation without limiting it to a single language. (For that matter, the principles can be taught without programming at all.) When you use a specific language, whether it's Java, Python, or what-have-you, it's easy to muddy the waters with language-specific nuance. For example, in Java we might be talking about the class or the object, but not all object-oriented languages are class-based (Javascript for one). The take-away? Don't expect to understand OOP from one language after a single course.

Comment: Look if your local library has got "James Rumbaugh, Michael Blaha, William Premerlani, Frederick Eddy, William Lorensen (1990). Object-Oriented Modeling and Design. Prentice Hall. ISBN 0-13-629841-9". It introduces object-orientation as a modelling technique and only later it discusses how to implement your object-oriented design in some concrete language. I found this reading very useful.

Comment: Java is honestly the father of OOP in my opinion. To really understand and be productive in Java, you've got to get through the hurdle of understanding OOP. If you learn OOP, you'll quickly grasp java: Take the "Master Object Oriented Design" course on http://eliminatecodefear.com - One of the best resources for learning practical object oriented design and development with HW assignments

Answer (score 23):

Java is a generally good OOP language. Sure it has fallen out of grace of the hipster hackers, but it is still one of the most used languages for OOP programming in the corporate world.

It's OOP principles are solid and you can draw valid comparisons between its design choices and other popular OOP languages like C++ and C# without any difficulty. Moreover, the design patterns applicable in OOP have almost always their Java version.

To sum up, if you have a good teacher that is willing to teach you OOP from Java, I would never dismiss such a good chance. However, if you want, you could complement it with comparing every principle you are taught with a couple other OOP languages version of it. That would help you achieve an almost agnostic OOP knowledge, that would ease a lot jumping to more trendy OOP languages.

Comment: Many design patterns are usually created to plug flaws in the language/paradigm. I don't think the fact that "the design patterns applicable in OOP have almost always their Java version" is a good thing.

Comment: Obviously all paradigms have their pitfalls and flaws. That being said, the fact that design patterns are potentially covering flaws in the OOP paradigm doesn't alter the fact that it is positive for an OOP language to let you use design patterns as a way to solve the flaws and shortcomings. We are not discussing, I think, if OOP is the panacea, which I don't think it is.

Comment: @celebdor: I think it's an important point that Java offers nothing but it's own OOP in every situation, even when that isn't the right tool for the job, and that it confuses OOP and many other paradigms *and* doesn't even offer everything that OOP has to offer

Comment: To make my previous comment clearer: I think that using design patterns to OO-ify stuff that is dead simple in other paradigms is not a good thing. I think that "learning OOP" (good) is not the same as "learning how to make everything OOP" (bad). Like you said OOP is not the panacea. Why teach it as such?

Comment: @DeadMG I agree with you in that Java OOP is not, by any means, an exhaustive or pure OOP. In my opinion, learning Java is a great way to see how a hugely adopted OOP looks like, at the cost of confusing Java with OOP. To avoid this, in the original post I recommended comparing what you learn along the way with other languages that have different and more pure implementations of the OOP paradigm.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes. You are right in saying that sometimes OOP design patterns are used to bend languages to do something which is not idiomatic in the OOP paradigm and, in those cases, it is obviously a better fit to re-evaluate if you are using the right tool for the task (unfortunately some people think they are the best tool for everything). However, for the cases in which your non functional requirements force you to constrain the options to an OOP language, it is nice to have the Design Patterns around.

Comment: The teacher is far more important than the language.  If you like him, then go ahead and learn Java.  If you have time, you can also start reading about another language that you may like better, and contrast the two.

Comment: @kevin: exactly. Besides, you can (and should) always learn different paradigms and languages from different sources; a Java passionate might not be as good a teacher if they focus on, say, Haskell; it also gives you various points of view.

Answer (score 13):

Right now, I'd probably say no. For example, Java disallows multiple inheritance- because the implementation is a little icky. There's nothing in any OOP theories stating that multiple inheritance should not be allowed- this is Java, not OOP. Multiple inheritance is a perfectly valid part of OOP that you can never learn about using Java.

More importantly, I wouldn't use Java to teach OOP because you would come off with the impression that OOP solves every problem and it's a hammer and everything is a nail, when in reality, generic programming and functional programming both have significant advantages in certain situations. Learning about OOP is not just about learning that it *can* be used in X situation or Y situation, but also when it *shouldn't* be applied.

It will also teach that object orientation is linked to other principles- for example, objects can only be heap allocated. What is an object, and where the memory for a type is stored, are two unrelated ideas, but Java couples the two concepts- not to mention how it also couples reference vs value semantics to objects, and other things, which I find ironic, because object orientation is all about decreasing coupling.

If you want to learn about OOP, including when it's not so hot or when it's implementation goes beyond the blindingly obvious, and you don't want to know about all of the Java-specific stuff they added on, then Java isn't the right thing to do. C++ would be a much better choice- it isn't afraid to offer you alternative paradigms and let you make the choice. If you learn C++, then you will learn much, much more than if you learned Java, and you won't get confused between object orientation and memory management, or object orientation and reference vs value semantics, and that kind of thing. Of course, it's also harder, so you get what you pay for here.

Of course, having the advantage of an actual teacher cannot be underestimated.

Comment: As a side not I would recommend against C++ as the first serious language you learn, because it's simply overwhelming.

Comment: The fact that Java is not allowing multiple inheritance is a good thing, not a bad thing.
The problem of m.i. is nicely explained in this article: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225929/what-is-the-exact-problem-with-multiple-inheritance

Comment: @eddy147: That's wrong. MI isn't perfect, that's no reason to disallow it. Just because in some cases it can be bad or ambiguous is no reason to throw it out.

Answer (score 4):

I saw first reality aspects of object orientation in C++. After I switched to Java and now I am a C# fan.

Actually I have heard that SmallTalk is the real object oriented, but I cannot say anything for myself.

I agree with celebdor that good examples from books of patterns and blah blah are in Java. for example Martin Fowler is a Java fan, and you cannot miss his books at all.

At the end, yes don't miss a good teacher for Java. learning it is not that bad :)

Answer (score 3):

First, While Java will help you to learn OOP, **you don't need it**. Also. **Java is not only OOP**, but Generic, Imperative and structured. Theoretically speaking, **Most OOP languages have a combination of other paradigms but OOP is the primary/dominat style form**.

Seconds, You can learn OOP from any language that supports it. Having said that, I would recommend to pick a "a pure OOP" because you might combine OOP idoms with the idioms of other paradigms (multi-paradigm). Examples of "pure" OOP popular languages that will help you to keep OO focus, could be **Scala** and **Ruby**.

Lastly, you might one to pick an agnostic-language-book on Object Oriented Analysis and Design (OOAD). This will help you to disconnect from a language-specific OOP and think in a more generic term. An easy fun book (it might be too java centric for you)  to read for me was [http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Object-Oriented-Analysis-Design/dp/0596008678](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596008678)

Armando.

Comment: Please mention "**"pure" OOP**" and **SmallTalk** in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I learned Java after I had learned VB.NET. I wished I had learned Java first, though, because I believe I learned the core concepts of OOP better in Java. And Java (or C#) is the next logical step if you've already worked in C based languages.

Comment: You're serious? VB.NET is pretty much C# in a verbose dress. I claim that you learning it better in Java is not related to the language, but to you and to how you relate to it.

Comment: And I agree. It probably didn't matter which language I learned second, it was just changing to another language that made me learn the actual OOP concepts behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a very good OOP language so would be a fine choice for learning OOP principles. The principles you will learn will be applicable in pretty much any other OOP language.

One of the advantages Java has from a teaching perspective is a relatively simple syntax, so that you can concentrate on learning the core OOP principles rather than concerning yourself too much with the complexity of the language (which could be a problem with C++, for example, which contains much more sophisticated features).

Also Java is a good language in its own right. Ignore the "naysayers" who have a tendency to bash Java on account of it's slightly verbose "old fashioned" syntax and lack of trendy features - it's high performance, maintainable, portable, popular and has the best ecosystem of libraries and tools of any language.

My personal suggestion would therefore be to learn OOP with Java, then if you genuinely feel a need to learn a more "trendy" language later you can easily pick up Clojure, Groovy or Scala (which have the advantage of building upon the Java platform)

Comment: Java is not a very good OOP language. It's an average OOP language.  Java has plenty of advantages, being a solid OOP language is not one of them

Comment: @Raynos - having learnt and taught many languages I totally disagree. Java is a very good OOP language from a learning perspective which is the context of this question. It will teach you all of the necessary OOP basics. Of the OOP features that Java does not include, most can be "considered harmful": duck typing, mixins, monkey patching, multiple inheritance, syntactic sugar for getters/setters etc. are emphatically *not* required to learn OOP and in some cases can lead to very bad practices and unmaintainable code.

Comment: You've marked all the lovely and powerful meta programming tools that make OO a joy as "harmful". You've got a watered down version of OO under the argument that we're making code more secure/maintainable by taking the gun away so you can't shoot yourself. This is a perfectly viable option but that means Java is no longer a "very good" OOP language

Comment: Maybe we just differ in opinion of what "very good" means then. When giving advice to beginners or typical organisations I prefer solid practices, maintainable code and long term productivity (assuming middling/average developers) above "joy to use" and advanced features that require considerable expertise to use safely. Beginners and average developers *will* shoot themselves in the foot more often than not in my experience. If you teach them solid foundations first, they are more likely to add value and have a successful career in the long run. They can have fun with Scala/Ruby then. YMMV.

Comment: @mikera there is the difference. I interpreted it as "Learn OOP theoretically", you interpreted it as "Learn OOP pragmatically". Sneak in a mindless edit and I'll undo the down vote because it's unfair.

Comment: OK then. If you only want to learn it theoretically I agree - Smalltalk is an easy winner! :-)